# Row_number does not work on timesheet data for same shift start date but different shift end date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on timesheet data where I have employee `shift_start_date`, `shift_start_time`, `shift_end_date`.

I've created a `row_num` column based on `shift_start_time`:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, shift_start_date 
                       ORDER BY shift_start_time asc) AS row_num
FROM 
    table
```

The data looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the `row_num` is incorrect for id 101. The employee starts the shift on '2020-10-04' but finishes it on '2020-10-05', so when ordering the rows by `shift_start_time`. It takes the 0:00 starttime as the the time that person has started the shift for that day and assigns `row_num = 1` for that row.

I want my data to look like this, where the `row_number_corrected` is the correct `row_number`:

[image]

Not sure how to fix this. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's numbering according to how you've told it, `0:00:00` is midnight morning. If they started on the 5th then shouldn't `shift_start_date` be `2020-10-05`?

Comment: Try moving `shift_start_date` from `PARTITION BY` clause to `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: it can be like a 8-11 hour shift and they've started the shift on '2020-10-04' and that shift lasted until next dat. So the column itself is like that. If you breakdown that shift then it technically is '2020-10-05'. But unfortunately that column is like that.

Comment: Hi Alex. But shift_start_date is the same for all the rows for 101. So it wouldn't give the output I'd want if I change that to ORDER BY.

Comment: based on the last row `2020-10-04 - 0:00:00 - 6:00:00` how do you know this is a continuation of a previous day shift ? And also the start date is actually `2020-10-05` and not `2020-10-04` ?

Comment: This code works properly based on the command written and the fields defined for it, and is also displayed in the image.

Comment: Hi Squirrel.  They strictly do not do split shift on the same day. i.e they may have not done their first shift on 0:00:00 - 6:00:00 and then again started another shift on same day 19:00:00 - 23:00:00 and then took a break from 23:00:00 - 00:00:00. So it is a continuation shift where they started at 19:00:00 and finished next day at 6:00:00

Comment: Hi Gezgalee. Yes the code works correctly for the part I've writted. But logically when you look at the output for id: 101, it is incorrect.

Comment: @Alex. I think what you have said is correct. change ```shift_start_date```  from partition to ORDER BY. But there should be another ```shift_start_date```  column like ```shift_start_date_correct``` that should be created with a case statement or something to add a day to the shift_start_date when time changes after midnight. And that new ```shift_start_date_correct``` can be used in the order by clause. Any idea how that column can be created? Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the actual start date. Like for the last row, the actual start date is `2020-10-05`

One way is to use recursive cte.

The anchor section finds the starting row. The starting row does not have another row with same `shift_end_time'. Subsequent rows is join by` shift_end_time = shift_start_time`

To get the actual start date, compare current row `shift_start_time` with next row. If next row `shift_start_time` is smaller, add 1 to the `act_start_date`

Finally concatenate `act_start_date` with `shift_start_time` to form datetime and used that for ordering

```
with rcte as
(
    -- Anchor
    select s.id, s.shift_start_date, s.shift_start_time, s.shift_end_time,
           act_start_date = s.shift_start_date
    from   shifts s
    where  not exists
           (
               select *
               from   shifts x
               where  x.id = s.id
               and    x.shift_start_date = s.shift_start_date
               and    x.shift_end_time   = s.shift_start_time
           )
           
    union all
    
    -- recursive
    select  s.id, s.shift_start_date, s.shift_start_time, s.shift_end_time,
            act_start_date = case when r.shift_start_time < s.shift_start_time
                                  then r.act_start_date
                                  else dateadd(day, 1, r.act_start_date)
                                  end
    from    rcte r
            inner join shifts s on  r.id = s.id
                                and r.shift_end_time = s.shift_start_time
)
select *,
       row_num = row_number() over (partition by id, shift_start_date
                                        order by convert(datetime, act_start_date) 
                                               + convert(datetime, shift_start_time))
from   rcte
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=98b891aab1f94fb615b770912a8a01e6)

Result :

| id | shift_start_date | shift_start_time | shift_end_time | act_start_date | row_num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2020-10-03 | 09:00:00 | 12:00:00 | 2020-10-03 | 1 |
| 100 | 2020-10-03 | 12:00:00 | 13:00:00 | 2020-10-03 | 2 |
| 100 | 2020-10-03 | 13:00:00 | 17:30:00 | 2020-10-03 | 3 |
| 101 | 2020-10-04 | 19:00:00 | 23:00:00 | 2020-10-04 | 1 |
| 101 | 2020-10-04 | 23:00:00 | 00:00:00 | 2020-10-04 | 2 |
| 101 | 2020-10-04 | 00:00:00 | 06:00:00 | 2020-10-05 | 3 |

Comment: Amazing! Never heard of recursive before. Learnt something today. Thank you very much.